# NesPi Safe Shutdown

Tags: scripts, xubuntu, shutdown, raspberrypi, arm

I have a NesPi case that I have successfully installed Ubuntu on and am trying to get the safe shutdown script to work. Does anyone know how to modify the script to get the safe shutdown feature to work while with Ubuntu rather than Raspbian, RetroPie, etc?

Edit: Here is the script in question.
https://github.com/RetroFlag/retroflag-picase/blob/master/install.sh

Edit: Thomas Ward pointed out that this is actually the script. Looks like above just installs this script.
https://github.com/RetroFlag/retroflag-picase/blob/master/SafeShutdown.py

Comment: You should probably include the script you're asking about.

Comment: Good idea. Just added it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what's 'safe' on this reboot with the script.  `/opt/RetroFlag/SafeShutdown.py` is the 'safe shutdown` script and not the one you linked.  So without *that* script I don't see how this is a 'safe' shutdown as it's just calling `sudo reboot`

Comment: Regarding my comment: found the script (https://github.com/RetroFlag/retroflag-picase/blob/master/SafeShutdown.py).  There's nothing really 'safe' on this I think, what I see it doing is a lot of GPIO stuff then LED blinks and then poweroff.  You'll need this script and its dependencies to trigger a shutdown process the way that rf-picase does.

Comment: All the script does is recognize when the power button is  pressed then trigger the shutdown process. If I could just locate in this script what triggers it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't run this in terminal after installing Ubuntu. I'm trying now after my card writes, I will try to update.

Comment: Did you try to run the script yourself?